# Unable to locate package kaltura-nginx

Tags: nginx, kaltura, vod

I am trying to install [Kaltura VOD Module (Github)](https://github.com/kaltura/nginx-vod-module) in my Ubuntu 20 machine. But when I run the command "apt-get install kaltura-nginx", it shows me the error "Unable to locate package kaltura-nginx". I dont get if the package is not available right now or I am doing anything wrong approach. So please suggest me on this.

```
# apt-get install kaltura-nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kaltura-nginx
```

**Environment used:** 
OS :Ubuntu 20.x 
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score -1):

Were you to download the package first?
For Ubuntu 20.04 add this repo:

```
wget -O - http://installrepo.kaltura.org/repo/aptn/focal/kaltura-deb-256.gpg.key|apt-key add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://installrepo.kaltura.org/repo/aptn/focal propus main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kaltura.list
```

Then install the kaltura-nginx package:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install kaltura-nginx
```